# Receiving the browser resolution using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I was needing a button that when the user clicks on the Submit button will goes to the next page called `step` and in this page will returns the user's resolution. I was trying to do the method below but it isn't working.

```
<?php
    echo '
    <script>
        function getSize() {
            var w = window.outerWidth;
            var h = window.outerHeight;
            document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "" + w + "x" + h + "px";
        }
    </script>';

    if (isset($_POST['step']) && $_POST['step'] == 'docreate') {
        // should receive the user resolution - I was trying to do with <p id="size"></p> but isn't working.
    } else {
        echo '
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="step" value="docreate" onclick="getSize()">Submit</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>';
    }
```

What I should use to make it works was I want it?

Comment: why dont you detect resolution on the next page? why post it from another page?

Comment: Are you trying get the width and height of body?document? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">` And than if you try to get rosulation, you will get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working. Since you are using a submit action, the script runs and then the page reloads - loosing any previous script results.

You can use.

```
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      var w = window.outerWidth;
      var h = window.outerHeight;
      document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = "" + w + "x" + h + "px"; 
      //--- save the values to the FORM
      document.getElementById('width).value = w;
      document.getElementById('height').value = h;
}
</script>
```

Extending the answer to include the form element

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="width" name="width" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="height" name="height" value="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="step" value="docreate">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked with your code, but now I'm facing a problem that I can't send the value to the database, the value display with `<p id="size"></p>`  Trying to use like this https://hastebin.com/cadayuhewo.pl

Comment: I saw that you edited your post, and I updated as well, but I couldn't receive the values of the width and the height yet, tried to use like this https://hastebin.com/izotarelog.scala

Comment: In your example you have <form onsubmit="return getSize();". Remove the onsubmit code as this function no longer exists and the values are stored into the form variables once the page is loaded. Also you have (maybe for demo purposes) echo sprintf("INSERT INTO - this isn't executing the sql statements.

Comment: I removed the form onSubmit, but also it isn't been executed because the value from widht and height isn't displaying. It is returning as `xpx` when I'm trying to use like `$_POST['width'].'x'.$_POST['height'].'px';`

Answer (score 1):

For the entire screen resolution, you can use

```
height = screen.height;
width = screen.width;
```

If you want resolution exluding the task bar, use

```
height = screen.availHeight;
width = screen.availWidth;
```